# Export multiple components as one from the same file in react

Tags: reactjs

someone could help me to achieve export several components so

```js
import { Card, Text } from "@nextui-org/react";

export default function App() {
  const MockItem = ({ text }) => {
    return (
      <Card css={{ h: "$20", $$cardColor: '$colors$primary' }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Text h6 size={15} color="white" css={{ m: 0 }}>
            {text}
          </Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import all the modules from one file and then destructure it to get what you need.

```
import * as multipleComponents from "@nextui-org/react";

const { Card, Text } = multipleComponents;
```

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one `export default` but there can be many `export const`

E.g.

```
export default function ...

export const MyOtherComponent = () => ...
```

You can swap `export const...` for `export function...` if you prefer.

Then to import them into another file -

```
import MyDefaultComponent, { MyOtherComponent } from '../path-to-components'
```